# At some zoom levels, dropdown menu has transparent gaps in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser, drop-down-menu

Please consider my stripped down code below that illustrates my issue.

If I run it in Firefox 7 or IE8, it works fine. However, when pressing F12 and entering the wonderful world of IE7, I'm experiencing gaps in my orange list at some zoom levels (so please use "ctrl+mouse wheel" when menu is extended to reproduce the bug).

The main annoyance there, excluding the aesthetic visual gap, is since my menu is defined as absolute, when the mouse stops on the gap my menu disappears.

Any suggestion on what is causing the problem?
Also what is the best way to handle it if an IE7 fix is required, in order that my menu remains exactly the same in other browsers?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBliC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>IE 7 Menu Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        line-height: 1;
      }

      ul li {
        background: #A0A0A0;
      }

      ul li ul li {
        background: #FF9900;
        display: block;
        white-space: normal;
        width: 200px;
      }

      ul ul {
        position: absolute;
      }

      div ul ul,div ul li:hover ul ul,div ul ul li:hover ul ul
        {
        display: none;
      }

      div ul li:hover ul,div ul ul li:hover ul,div ul ul ul li:hover ul
        {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>

  <div><ul><li>Menu
      <!-- drop down list -->
      <ul>
        <li>- One</li>
        <li>- Two</li>
        <li>- Three</li>
        <li>- Four</li>
      </ul><!-- end drop down list -->
  </li></ul></div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Zooming may not scale to pixels as you want it to... there's really no solution at all. Browsers didn't have "full page zoom" back then.

Comment: @Chris  me to I’m fatalist when it comes to ie7, but I’m just asking to see what sticks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're experiencing this bug: http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEWlispace.php

As you can see, different combinations cause the problem, so there are various way to fix it.

Here's your original code: http://jsbin.com/itaxek

One possible fix is to move `width: 200px;` from `ul li ul li` to `ul ul`: http://jsbin.com/itaxek/2

Comment: Thx for the link helped me understand what is going on. It was fun to see my peace of code online ;)
+ your fix suggestion work well and is what I’m going to adopt